# Aligning text columns

Tags: vertical-alignment, horizontal-alignment

I am using the following code to try to obtain something to the effect of

```
Author:                      Laboratory Partners:
Amos NG                      Rebecca ROYCROFT
                             Nora BRACKBILL
Professor:
Huan HUANG
```

The code:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushleft} \small
\emph{Author:}\\
Amos \textsc{Ng}\\[0.4cm]
\emph{Professor:} \\
Huan \textsc{Huang}
\end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
\begin{flushright} \small
\emph{Laboratory Partners:} \\
Rebecca \textsc{Roycroft}\\
Nora \textsc{Brackbill}
\end{flushright}
\end{minipage}
```

The resulting output:

[image]

How can I achieve the layout I want here?

Comment: try `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth} ` for the two `minipage` environments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're trying to get the effect of having the longest line on the right appear flush-right.

Rather than `minipage` I'd be inclined to use top-aligned `tabular`, as these automatically adjust their size, with an `\hfill` to align them to their respective edges.

Edit: Added @{} to the column specs to remove whitespace at the margins.

Something like this:

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
\emph{Author:}\\
Amos \textsc{Ng}\\
\rule{0.4cm}{0cm}\\% A strut for the extra line space
\emph{Professor:} \\
Huan \textsc{Huang}
\end{tabular}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
\small
\emph{Laboratory Partners:} \\
Rebecca \textsc{Roycroft}\\
Nora \textsc{Brackbill}
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is two thing you could use:

- minipage have an optional position parameter that you should set to t
  for top aligning
- the \hfill command will create a space between the 2 mimipage that
  will fill all available place.

  ```
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
   .....
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
  .....
  \end{minipage}
  ```

Comment: `hfill`is not necessary. The OP uses `flushleft`and `flushright so it's possible to modify the size of the minipages like this : `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}`

Comment: In is exemple, it seem that he wanted to flushleft the right part, hence the hfill.